# ROPC or Client Credential Grant for 1st party centralized-account app?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

We are developing app-1 and app-2 REST API where accounts will be managed by a single account(company). Something similar when you need atlassian account for you jira and confluence application.

Im quite confuse where to place the `/login` endpoint and where to create session. What I'm sure is that session must be created at oauth2 provider (authorization + resource) considering 3rd party oauth2 client in the future.

The way I see it in ROPC, I will have a `/login` at oauth2-client and use the credential to send a `password grant_type` request to authorization server, create access token and bind to a session. sessionID must be returned to the User-agent for the succeeding resource endpoint request. While in Client Credential Grant, I see authorization server having the /login and endpoint and issuing sessionID directly to user agent.

Access Token must stay within the server-side right?

Follow Up Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40148613/ropc-and-oidc-for-rest-api-1st-and-3rd-party-clients

Comment: I tried to address the question on the tile and the last one about access tokens, but in relation to the endpoint confusion I have to admit that I'm also confused. Can you try to make your scenario more clear?

Comment: @JoãoAngelo I just was confuse yesterday about the how to handle session, whether if session will be managed in client(oauth2) or authorization server. Now my conclusion is i need to have a small client like id.atlassian.com for the purpose of 3rd party application when you need login to have an active session before you authorize the application. So session managment will happen in the oauth2 clients right?

Comment: There may be more than one session, one managed by authentication/authorization server that keeps track that you logged in, while the client application can maintain a session so that they don't have to be always asking who the user is. After the first authentication, client may create a session to reduce number of requests to an authentication server.

Comment: @JoãoAngelo am I on the right track, this is my follow up question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40148613/ropc-and-oidc-for-rest-api-1st-and-3rd-party-clients, hope i can have your opinion on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a significant difference between resource owner password credentials grant (ROPC) and client credentials grant (CC); there is no separate resource owner involved on the second.

With CC you just have an application acting on behalf of itself and accessing resources that are likely not in the scope of a given user. This is illustrated in the following diagram:

[image: OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Grant Flow]

(source: [Client Credentials Grant](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/grant/client-credentials))

If your client application **interacts with the API on behalf of a user then this is not the grant you're looking for**.

In relation to the access tokens question, the answer is no, an access token can be made available to a client application outside of a server environment. There is added security risks, but if this was not possible mobile applications and browser-based application would have no way to access an API that requires them.

Comment: For clarification: there is __always__ a resource owner involved in an OAuth2 grant type flow (otherwise the framework protocol has no sense). With the CC, the resource owner is the client. This is clearly explained in the [RFC6749 section-1.3.4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.3.4)

Comment: No doubt about that and you're right that's the way the spec calls it so that's what wins. Personally, I just find it can add more confusion due to terminology overload. Nonetheless, I'll update the answer to make it more clear. Thanks.

Comment: access token is what i need to get access to the resource right, how is this security weakness address in mobile or browser-based application?

Comment: Yes, the access token is generally used to give you access to protected resources. In mobile or browser-based applications you still need to store the token even though there are more security risks. Check the [where to store tokens](https://auth0.com/blog/cookies-vs-tokens-definitive-guide/) section of this article, for some risks in the browser world.